# How can i get argparse to accept no arguments if the user hasn't passed one and use a variable as the argument instead (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters, arguments, argparse

How can i get my log parser to accept no arguments if the user hasn't passed one and use the generated log that's stored in the log variable.

```
    #####################
    #LogFile
    #####################
    log =(sys.argv[2])
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log ,level=logging.DEBUG)

    if log == "-p" or log == "--path":
        TIME_STAMPS = re.split('\s+', time.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S %H:%M:%S', time.localtime()))
        FILE_TIME_STAMP = TIME_STAMPS[0] + "_" + TIME_STAMPS[1]
        log = "version" + "_" + FILE_TIME_STAMP + "_ValidLinkCheck.log"
        logging.basicConfig(filename=log ,level=logging.DEBUG)
    ########################
    #Command Line Options
    ########################
    #initiate the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-l','--log', dest='log', default = 'log1' , help = "Log File", action="store_true", required= False)
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", action="store", help="path to file", dest="filename")
    parser.add_argument("-x", "--execute", help="delete invalid link", action="store_true")

    #read arguments from the command line
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #check for --path or -p
    if args.filename:
        print("Script is up to date and running.......................")
        logging.info("Script is up to date and running.......................")
        path = (format(args.filename)) 
        logging.info("Searching for input link" + path)
        status, result = commands.getstatusoutput('cd ' + path)
```

Comment: Read [argparse.html#default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default)

Comment: Turn off the `required`, and provide a `default`

Comment: @stovfl it doesn't work here's the output that it gives me                    
 usage: validLinkCheck.py [-h] [-l LOG] [-p FILENAME] [-x]           
 validLinkCheck.py: error: argument -l/--log: expected one argument

Comment: @hpaulj for some reason the loggin.info(..........) doesn't get passed inside the log file.  here's the output i get                                                                                                         cat: version_20190111_120658_ValidLinkCheck.log: No such file or directory

Comment: It's hard to figure out what your code is doing.  You set `log` from `sys.argv`, and never use `args.log`.

Comment: @PalQeis: *"error: argument -l/--log: expected one argument"*: [Edit] your Question and show the updated `add_argument('-l','--log', ...` code line.

Comment: @hpaulj no worries guys i've solved it. & i'm going to update the code soon

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Your question should remain strictly a question, though you are more than welcome to post an answer as well. (Your edits are still visible in the [edit history.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54149075/revisions))